# Maintaining state when switching tabs in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack

In Jetpack Compose if I use a Structure that has tabs at the the top of the screen and I want to change the view in the body but maintain the state of each body's content, is this done by simply having multiple bodies and hiding/showing each one as you click on the tabs by setting each with View.visibility = VISIBLE or GONE? Or is this done differently using Compose?

By maintaining state, this would include the scroll position of the content on each body.

Answer (score 2):

Just stuff everything into your viewmodel. That's my way

Comment: As for scroll, there is a ```rememberScrollState``` Method as well so you can also store that in your viewmodel

Comment: Maybe could you explain why you do this and what's the point of doing it ?

Comment: Adding stuff in the viewmodel?

Comment: In Jetpack Compose, variables are used to store the state of the UI. Hence, if the variables are locally maintained, there are good chances that some parts of the code reflect another state as compared to another part. Hence, WE STORE ALL THE STATE IN THE VIEWMODEL which acts as a single source of truth for the app. Whichever part needs to read variables to access state, dress it directly through the viewmodel. Make sense?